# gtsummary: univariable and multivariable

Tags: gtsummary

everyone,recently I used the R package gtsummary to creating univariable and multivariable models using coxph in gtsummary,but there is an error as follow,

add_global_p: Global p-values for variable(s) `add_global_p(include = c("Age", "Gender", "Path_T", "Path_N", "Path_M", "Path_stage", "TP53"))` were calculated
with
`car::Anova(x$model_obj, type = "III")`
x `add_global_p()` uses `car::Anova()` to calculate the global p-value,
and the function returned an error while calculating the p-values.
Is your model type supported by `car::Anova()`?
Error in df.terms.default(mod) : Model has aliased term(s); df ambiguous.

My code is below,

```
library(gtsummary)
data<-read.table("patient_data.txt",sep="\t",header=T)
data1<-na.omit(data)
    library(survival)
      tbl_uvsurv <- select(data1,everything()) %>%
         tbl_uvregression(
            method=coxph,
             y=Surv(Time,Status),
             exponentiate=TRUE
         )  %>%
      add_global_p() %>%
      bold_p(t=0.05)%>%
     bold_labels()
```

## A multivariable table:

```
library(survival)
  tbl_mvsurv <-coxph(
   Surv(Time,Status) ~.,
        data=data1
   ) %>%
  tbl_regression(
      exponentiate=TRUE
   ) %>%
   add_global_p() %>%
  bold_p(t=0.05)%>%
 bold_labels()
```

Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can best answer your question when you provide a reproducible example, meaning providing code we can run on our machines utilizing a publicly available dataset (or a simulated data set). Below are two examples: one of a multivariable model and one a table of univariable models.

```r
library(survival)
#> Warning: package 'survival' was built under R version 4.1.1
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.2'
# multivariable model
tbl1 <-
  coxph(Surv(ttdeath, death) ~ age + trt, trial) %>%
  tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  add_global_p()
#> add_global_p: Global p-values for variable(s) `add_global_p(include = c("age",
#> "trt"))` were calculated with
#>   `car::Anova(x$model_obj, type = "III")`
```

[image]

```r
# univariable model
tbl2 <-
  trial %>%
  select(ttdeath, death, age, trt) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    y = Surv(ttdeath, death),
    method = coxph,
    exponentiate = TRUE
  ) %>%
  add_global_p()
#> add_global_p: Global p-values for variable(s) `add_global_p(include = c("age",
#> "trt"))` were calculated with
#>   `car::Anova(mod = x$model_obj, type = "III")`
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: When runing my code with the data,the error is still exist,as follow,
add_global_p: Global p-values for variable(s) add_global_p(include = c("Age", "Gender", "Path_T", "Path_N", "Path_M", "Path_stage", "TP53")) were calculated with car::Anova(x$model_obj, type = "III") x add_global_p() uses car::Anova() to calculate the global p-value, and the function returned an error while calculating the p-values. Is your model type supported by car::Anova()? Error in df.terms.default(mod) : Model has aliased term(s); df ambiguous.

Comment: There is letter to do if we can't replicate your error on our machines. If you post the data, or a small smaller of the data along with your code that can reproduce the error, we can look into it further.  If needed, read more on asking good questions on SO by including a reproducible example, aka a reprex

Comment: I found that if there was a Inf in the output results,the error will